# Package titletoc doesn't make changes to Hebrew document

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, hebrew, titletoc

In a Hebrew document, it seems that `\titlecontents{chapter}...` doesn't make any formatting changes to the way chapters appear in my table of contents. Though for sections and subsections it works fine.

The chapters should be printed in Large italicized with the chaptername before its number.

Any idea why and how to solve it?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]
  {\Large\itshape}
  {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\ }
  {}
  {\hfill\contentspage}
  []

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{אלגברה}
\section*{הקדמה}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{הקדמה}
\section{א}
\section{ב}
\section{ג}
\section{ד}
\chapter{גיאומטריה}
\section{א}
\section{ב}
\section{ג}
\section{ד}
\section{ה}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`polyglossia` loads a package called `bidi` when Hebrew is used in the document. `bidi` redefines the macro `\l@chapter` so that the chapters entry in the `toc` would look appropriately for a RTL document.

So, you can simply use `\titlecontents` after `bidi` is loaded:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}



\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{\Large\itshape}
{\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\ }
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}
[]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{אלגברה}
    \section*{הקדמה}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{הקדמה}
    \section{א}
    \section{ב}
    \section{ג}
    \section{ד}
    \chapter{גיאומטריה}
    \section{א}
    \section{ב}
    \section{ג}
    \section{ד}
    \section{ה}
\end{document}
```