# Diacritic on last Hebrew letter

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew, diacritical-mark

I'm using the `polyglossia` package to write Hebrew text, with Hebrew set as the second language (`\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`). However, I'm facing an issue where the diacritic point on the last letter of the Hebrew word doesn't appear in the correct position (refer to the attached picture). I'm compiling the document using XeLaTeX. Can anyone provide a solution for this problem?
The original code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=black,
%    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
%    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[autostyle, english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}             
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL_Hbrw.ttf}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\scshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\quad\scshape\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\capitalisewords{#1}}} % Modified



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\scshape\Large}
{\filleft\textcolor{gray}{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont{\thechapter}}}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\scshape}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\thesubsubsection}
{1em}
{}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\title{Hebrew}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blank[1]{\rule[-.2ex]{#1}{.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{contents}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{list of figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{list of tables}

\section{Some section}
Since in Biblical Hebrew geminated consonants are not allowed word-finally, we see alternations such as \texthebrew{ֹעַמּו} [ʕammo], `his people' vs. \texthebrew{עַם} [ʕam], `people'.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You're right, sorry. This is my first post!

Answer (score 2):

The error can be obtained with much shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\font\hebrew"David CLM Medium:script=hebr;" at 12.0pt % I don't have SBL_Hbrw.ttf on my system...
\TeXXeTstate1

\begin{document}
    \hebrew\beginR ֹעַמּו
\end{document}
```

Just for a reference, this is how TeXstudio renders this text:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is probably not related to `fontspec` nor `polyglossia`, in fact this is just a "feature" of [Unicode bidirectional algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/) , which your text editor is using, and not related to `TeX` at all.

I'm guessing that the Unicode glyph  `U+05B9` (or "Holam") is considered as a neutral character (with regards to directionality), and since the word `עמו` is written inside a block with `LTR` as base direction, and the Holam is not in between two strong `RTL` characters, it inherits the `LTR` directionality from the paragraph, and so is placed to the left of the word, although it is presents in the beginning of the word and not at the end of it.

You can test it simply by putting the hebrew word in a separate block of text, which does not affect how TeX process the code:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\font\hebrew"David CLM Medium:script=hebr;" at 12.0pt
\TeXXeTstate1

\begin{document}
    \hebrew\beginR
     ֹעַמּו
\end{document}
```

Well, this site does not render the hebrew text quite well, but in TeXstudio it appears as

[image]

As you can see, the holam is at the beginning of the word... so the solution is simple, move it to the correct place.

Unrelated to the question, bu you should not use `inputenc` nor `fontenc` with XeTeX, and since `polyglossia` loads `bidi` when using hebrew, you should probably load it near the end of the preamble, polyglossia already loads `fontspec`, so you don't need to load it as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[autostyle, english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=black,
    %    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    %    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}             
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL_Hbrw.ttf}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\scshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\quad\scshape\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\capitalisewords{#1}}} % Modified



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\scshape\Large}
{\filleft\textcolor{gray}{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont{\thechapter}}}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
    \vspace{2ex}%
    \filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\scshape}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\thesubsubsection}
{1em}
{}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}



\title{Hebrew}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \makeatletter
    \def\hlinewd#1{%
        \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
        \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
    \makeatother
    
    \newcommand\blank[1]{\rule[-.2ex]{#1}{.4pt}}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{contents}
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{list of figures}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{list of tables}
    
    \section{Some section}
    Since in Biblical Hebrew geminated consonants are not allowed word-finally, we see alternations such as \texthebrew{עַמּוֹ} [ʕammo], `his people' vs. \texthebrew{עַם} [ʕam], `people'.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Unrelated to this, when I load ```polyglossia``` *after* ```titlesec``` and ```fancy```, I lose all the title/section and header formatting. Do you know what could be the issue here?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681293/264024 . I will edit accordingly.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, load `bidi` after most packages, but any formatting to the layout should happen after `bidi` is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a slightly simpler example than that given by Udi Fogiel:

The problem is that you have typed (or copied) the wrong word into your editor.

You have typed `\texthebrew{ֹעַמּו}`, but you should have `\texthebrew{עַמּוֹ}`

I doubt this is a problem with the Unicode bi-directional algorithm (I don't have any problem typing this into other editors). If you typed the word in directly, it's more likely a bug in the editor.

Try this example to compare what you had and what you should have had:

```
% TeX Program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}             
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate]{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
Your code: \texthebrew{ֹעַמּו}

Correct code: \texthebrew{עַמּוֹ}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Indeed I've tried several editors, and it seems that the "problem" only occurs only when they use Unicode bidi algorithm at its full, including (and very importantly) making RTL paragraphs when the first letter is strong RTL. For example, with notepad++ it does not happen, but it only implements the algorithm for sentences, not for paragraphs. Which editors did you try? I'm actually on a search for an editor that is convenient for mixed directional writing.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Ah, interesting - probably not ones that automatically create RTL paragraphs. My main editor is `vim` and that doesn't display RTL at all, so I have to learn to read Hebrew LTR…

Comment: @UdiFogiel, still odd that your editors get it wrong. The bidi algorithm is only supposed to affect display. I would have thought that the holem should just combine with the previous character entered, no matter what direction things are running in.

Comment: Yes, `vim` does not use any bidi related stuff automatically, but you can change everything from LTR to RTL, so you can switch direction when you write hebrew text, I remember the command currently.

Comment: I might be wrong about unicode bidi algorithm, mayb it is just a problem with TeXstudio